# Is there possibility for FreeMarker to create a directory or package on Android Studio templating?

Tags: android-studio, freemarker

I'm trying to create a template that has a nested package.

Here's my templating code.

```
// root/global.xml.ftl

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<globals>
    <global id="simpleLayoutName" value="${layoutName}"/>
    <global id="excludeMenu" type="boolean" value="true"/>
    <global id="resOut" value="${resDir}"/>
    <global id="srcOut" value="${srcDir}/${slashedPackageName(packageName)}"/>
    <#include "../common/common_globals.xml.ftl" />
</globals>
```

```
// root/recipe.xml.ftl

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<recipe>
    <#if generateLayout>
        <#include "../common/recipe_simple.xml.ftl" />
        <open file="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/layout/${layoutName}.xml"/>
    </#if>

    <instantiate from="root/src/app_package/SimpleFragment.kt.ftl"
                 to="${escapeXmlAttribute(srcOut)}/${activityClass}Fragment.kt"/>
</recipe>
```

```
// root/template.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template
        format="5"
        revision="1"
        name="MVVM Activity"
        minApi="9"
        minBuildApi="14"
        description="Creates a new empty activity that uses MVVM Pattern">

    <category value="Activity" />
    <formfactor value="Mobile" />

    <parameter
        id="generateLayout"
        name="Generate Layout File"
        type="boolean"
        default="true"
        help="If true, a layout file will be generated" />

    <parameter
        id="layoutName"
        name="Layout Name"
        type="string"
        constraints="layout|unique|nonempty"
        suggest="${activityToLayout(activityClass)}"
        default="activity_main"
        visibility="generateLayout"
        help="The name of the layout to create for the activity" />

    <parameter
        id="packageName"
        name="Package name"
        type="string"
        constraints="package"
        default="com.mycompany.myapp" />

    <!-- 128x128 thumbnails relative to template.xml -->
    <thumbs>
        <!-- default thumbnail is required -->
        <thumb>template_MVVM_activity.png</thumb>
    </thumbs>

    <globals file="globals.xml.ftl" />
    <execute file="recipe.xml.ftl" />

</template>
```

```
// root/src/app_package/SimpleFragment.kt.ftl

package ${packageName}

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

class ${fragmentClass}Fragment : Fragment() {

    // TODO: Implement by lazy ViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // TODO: Init or setup view, viewmodel related, etc anything to setup here
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // TODO: Init or setup view, viewmodel related, etc anything to setup here
    }
}
```

But, I didn't find any function to create a directory here: http://freemarker.apache.org/docs

Looks like I'm missing something here, is there anyone ever doing this to achieve creating a package inside output directory.

I quite catch that `recipe.xml.ftl` able to instantiate new file, but I still didn't try to create a directory instead, is it possible? What should add for `from` attribute value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [article](https://medium.com/@factoryhr/how-to-speed-up-development-by-using-mvp-templates-for-android-studio-37174546c1b8). By default, you can do this without any extra effort. Just point the new package on `recipe.xml.ftl` e.g:

```
<instantiate from="root/src/main/java/model/Simple.kt.ftl"
             to="${escapeXmlAttribute(srcOut)}/model/${modelName}.kt"/>
```

`to` element will creating the new `model` package inside your destination directdory.